# Which time to add constraint to superView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I wanna add constraints to`Aview` on `Aview.superView` without Xib and Storyboard, i add constraint code in the function `-(void)didMoveToSuperview`, it worked. The second time i add `Aview` to `cell.contentView`, when i start to scroll , it crashed; 

Here is the error info :

`A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs`

But i am sure all the params of the multiplier is not 0 or nil .
It seems that the second item(the superView) is nil , so i write the constraint code in a custom function like this :

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];
[view setConstraint];
```

Then it works;

I just wanna know is there a good way to add constraint in the `Aview`?In which function ?

Comment: before add subview in main view you need to add constrain of your subview

Comment: but a lot of constrain of subView needs add on the mainView , so i just can add it after the subView added to mainView, is not it ?